# Click to add contact in the mobile web

Tags: html, vcf-vcard

Is there any solution that able to add a contact (into mobile device)through the website? just like the QRCode vCard which can scan and add contact

Comment: We would need more information about your website. You can pretty easily create dynamic vCards in JS that will work with iOS and Android from mobile browsers. Something like https://github.com/enesser/vCards-js definitely fits the bill.

Comment: @pj100 cool.. using php framework (laravel)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a vcard generator package that will work with Laravel. It does have fallbacks to ensure it works with iOS which doesn't support .vcf files.

https://packagist.org/packages/jeroendesloovere/vcard

you can install it with `composer require jeroendesloovere/vcard1`